# PHP access file from online download link rather than direct

Tags: php, download, google-sheets

I have an online spreadsheet located on google drive. This spreadsheet is public and is accessible through a url. Appending `export?format=csv` to the public url opens a download prompt which allows a client-side viewer to download the CSV version of the online spreadsheet file to their computer by selecting a file location and clicking "download".

What I want to do is allow my PHP script to interact with Google's supplied download link `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?format=csv`

Rather than a direct download link like `www.example.com/file.csv`

Since google uses the `$_GET` value of `?format=csv` to direct the client to the download, I cannot just use `include_once()` or a similar method to access the file in my script, as that would access the HTML file responsible for displaying the google spreadsheet.

How can I access this online download through PHP if it is not a direct download link? Other methods outside of PHP are welcome as well, so long as I can access the CSV file's data through PHP (or download it to the server, either temporarily or permanently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days of confusion an problem solving, I finally figured this one out based on multiple tutorials and examples around the web. None of them exactly matched my needs, but basically this is what I came up with **to download a published Google Spreadsheet from the internet *without* using the Google API**.

```
$fileid = "spreadsheet file id here";
$url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/".$fileid."/export?format=csv&id=".$fileid;

$newfilename = "newfile";

$file = fopen($url,"r");

$output = fopen($newfilename.'.csv', 'wb');

while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
       fputcsv($output, $data);
}

fclose($file);
fclose($output);
```

Upon running this code, the script takes the data from the Google Spreadsheet and outputs it to the newly created file determined by `$newfilename.csv` in `text/csv` format.

I hope this helps someone in the future. I've seen many topics around SO and the rest of the web as to how to access Google Spreadsheet data in CSV format without the API, and after never finding a real answer not involving the API, I think I've done it!

Answer (score 4):

Simple `file_get_contents()` should work just fine in your case.

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?format=csv');
```

Comment: This just gives me the surrounding HTML page in this case. Rather than giving me the CSV data as `$content`. Any other ideas??